# Is there any chance to get a button with double clicked after disabling it with one click?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, playframework

Getting very confusion with button clicks in my html page.I have set a function to my button id to avoid double clicks.Double clicks causes double entries in my database.It works fine up to now.But today again i got one double entry in my database.I unable to find what is the reason for getting this issue.There is no errors also in my java class and jquery.Please help me in finding solution.For all help thanks in advance.

```
My jquery code is:
 $(function()
  {
  $('#timesheetForm').submit(function(){
  $("input[type='submit']", this).val("Please Wait...")
  .attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  setTimeout('$("#btnSubmitInTimesheet").removeAttr("disabled")', 1500);
  $("input[type='submit']", this).val("Submit")
  return true;
 });
});
```

Java method:

```
    public static Result save(Long storeId) {
    System.out.println("inside save method===========");
    Store store = Store.find.byId(storeId);

    Long empId = Long.parseLong(form().bindFromRequest().get("empid"));
    String startDate = form().bindFromRequest().get("date");
    String endDate = form().bindFromRequest().get("endDate");
    String leaveType = form().bindFromRequest().get("leaveType");
    String status = form().bindFromRequest().get("status");

    Employee employee = Employee.find.byId(empId);
    System.out.println("Selected Employee Id is ========" + employee.id);
    String jobTitle = employee.designation;
    String firmType = "STORE";

    if (!leaveType.equals("None")) { // if he selected one leave type

        Timesheet.create(empId, startDate, endDate, leaveType, "0", "0",
                "0", "0", "0:0", jobTitle, firmType, storeId, status);
    } else {
        String startHours = form().bindFromRequest().get("startTimeHour");
        String startMins = form().bindFromRequest().get("startTimeMins");
        String endHours = form().bindFromRequest().get("endTimeHour");
        String endMins = form().bindFromRequest().get("endTimeMins");
        String duration = form().bindFromRequest().get("duration");

        Timesheet.create(empId, startDate, endDate, leaveType, startHours,
                startMins, endHours, endMins, duration, jobTitle, firmType,
                storeId, status);
        System.out.println("employeee saved is=========" + employee);
    }
    System.out.println("Timesheet saved=========");
    return redirect(routes.Timesheets.showBlank(storeId));
}
```

Comment: "Double clicks causes double entries in my database" - fix the database / backend part. You should not trust the client to send you the right data.

Comment: I have given form validation that is same values they cannot submitted again.it will check with database .

Comment: Are you sure the submit event is bound??? FYI, you should use `.prop('disbaled', true);` to disable it but i'm not sure it would be an issue here. BTW, don't use string as setTimeout callback, use anonymous function. Now comes the question, why using `$("#btnSubmitInTimesheet").removeAttr("disabled")` to reenable button? Why ID selector there but not for disabling it? And don't use removeAttr, still use `.prop()`

Comment: can u please explain small sample code to disable a button with prop()

Comment: @dnvsp What about: `Are you sure the submit event is bound???` Because it more looks like your issue comes from here, the submit event isn't bound. In fact, your observation regarding double base entry could be for many many causes and without being able to test it, we can just guessing. And btw if you don't answer any question but instead ask new ones, it will last long...

Comment: @A.wolff yes my submit button worked through jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to disable the button on submit, so that it can only be pressed one time.

Comment: firstly i tried with to disable a button on submit only.i have updated code and you can see there.After that i tried with button click